# nginx (2: no such file or directory) - laravel on ubuntu server

Tags: 16.04, server, nginx, laravel

I just installed and pushed the code server. when I try to access the other pages I'm getting nginx  error like as below

> *1 open() "/var/www/html/domain/public/admin" failed (2: No such file or directory),

server block of code is :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/domain/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain.com;

    location /phpmyadmin/ {
       try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I have tried all possible solutions.But I keep getting the error. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Is there such a file as /var/www/html/domain/public/admin? What does your error log show when you try to access it?

Comment: @vidarlo : Thank you for the response :). Yes its there . I figured out the issue was with server block code where we mention the location `{  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; }` .